# Calling Env State Tuple

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm new to Open Ai Gym and currently running Reinforcement Learning (RL) in the Taxi Environment and my research requires me to be able to call the State tuple (or called "State Space" in the `Taxi.py` file ) for some data mining / state-action pair operation.

Is there a function to call this?

Eg: `State(123) = (taxi_row, taxi_col, passenger_location, destination)`

In RL the state and actions are represented in matrices form, `column = state, row = action`.

In the source code (`taxi.py`) its called "state space is represented by (`taxi_row`, `taxi_col`, `passenger_location`, `destination`)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like so:

```
>>> import gym
>>> env = gym.make('Taxi-v2')
>>> from gym.envs.toy_text.taxi import *
>>> 
>>> 
>>> x = TaxiEnv()
>>> random_state = 123
>>> taxi_row, taxi_col, passenger_index, destination_index = x.decode(random_state)
>>> taxi_row
1
>>> taxi_col
1
>>> passenger_index
0
>>> destination_index
3
```

In your question, you want the `passenger_location` and `destination`. But the code I used was returning the `passenger_index` and `destination_index`. So, you can get the location easily if you understood the environment map.

The following is the simple map used in the environment:

```
MAP = [
    "+---------+",
    "|R: | : :G|",
    "| : | : : |",
    "| : : : : |",
    "| | : | : |",
    "|Y| : |B: |",
    "+---------+",
]
```

In this map, we have four different locations (R, G, Y, B). Now, you can get the passenger location and destination easily knowing the index like so:

- Passenger locations:

  - 0: R(ed)
  - 1: G(reen)
  - 2: Y(ellow)
  - 3: B(lue)
  - 4: in taxi
- Destinations:

  - 0: R(ed)
  - 1: G(reen)
  - 2: Y(ellow)
  - 3: B(lue)

Hope this answers your question!!

Comment: Thanks. I tested for def encode to get the state from a given tuple (in reverse from the given solution) and it checked out. I guess i'm in luck since the taxi.py already has the function coded. Any chance the FrozenLake environment has the same function? but doesn't seem like it though. Thanks alot.